# Using the QUERY formula in Google Sheets to transform 12 month columns into a column with month name and a column with value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm basically trying to turn a data table that has a the following structure in columns A:O with ~10k records, all contain unique combinations of the first 3 column with their monthly amounts spent or forecasted in each of the months

CostCentre/LedgerAccount/SpendCategory/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec/Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug

I'm trying to import and transform the data in to:

CostCentre/LedgerAccount/SpendCategory/Month/Value

Right now I'm importing the data and then putting it through a pivot table to align the months into one column and the rows into another. Is there a way to use the QUERY formula or another formula to transpose this data? I know of the transpose function, but I can't seem to make it work as I only want to transpose the month columns and not the first 3

here is a doc with a sample of the data table, and a tab with my desired results https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gm9fX_r19rOiXhhL4A07S6us4hYEqGij9tfO5rPANIk/edit#gid=1027621977

Comment: Could you create a sample spreadsheet with dummy data and what you'd expect it to look, to work with it?

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. Here is a quick work book with a sample of the dataset and a desired outcome tab  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gm9fX_r19rOiXhhL4A07S6us4hYEqGij9tfO5rPANIk/edit#gid=1027621977

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes a possible answer using REDUCE. It scans each cell, and stacks the corresponding values of columns A:D (based on the row of the value) and of row 1:1 (the month, based on the column of the value):

```
=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),'Data Table'!E2:P,LAMBDA(a,v,
IF(v="",a,
VSTACK(a,HSTACK(INDEX('Data Table'!A:D,ROW(v)),INDEX('Data Table'!1:1,COLUMN(v)),v)))))
```

[image]

Comment: This does work exactly as I was hoping it would, thank you. Unfortunately, it seems to be crashing Google Sheets when I try on a larger dataset. I'm not sure if I'll be able to use it for what I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

*[Try with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gm9fX_r19rOiXhhL4A07S6us4hYEqGij9tfO5rPANIk/edit#gid=745537054):*

```js
=let(months_values_,E2:P, months_header_,E1:P1, rep_,A2:D, Σ,index(match(,0/(A2:A<>""))),
     reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(Σ),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(chooserows(index(rep_,c),sequence(columns(months_header_),1,1,0)),tocol(months_header_),tocol(index(months_values_,c)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works great as well, thank you. I think this will be extremely useful for me for smaller data tables.  The larger data tables keep crashing Google Sheets though.

Comment: Just to get an idea how many rows of data are we looking at in your larger dataset?!

Comment: ~6500 rows. I adjusted the receiving sheet to have all the rows it needs, but I think it's just too much for it